# How can I change the color of one part of my menu-header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to put the title "ENGLISH" of my menu header in blue. http://investiretplus.com/
It is a link.
I don't find the html line of code in the wordpress interface.
But I found this:

```
<div class="pagenav">
    <?php if(has_nav_menu( 'main-menu' )) wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header',    'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'walker' => new description_walker() ) ); ?>
```

Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your css style sheet should work:

```
li#menu-item-915 a strong 
{
    color: #009fff;
}
```

This will change the font color from `#666666` to `#009fff` to that menu item (because it has an id of `menu-item-915`.

Comment: @cmatte, you might need to do a hard refresh of the page.

Answer (score 1):

On your WordPress admin panel, access to the "Menus" configuration page (Appearance -> Menus).

Click on the "Screen Options" tab on the top of the page and check the "CSS Class" checkbox.

Now, you have the ability to add CSS classes to your menu items (`<li>`).

Add your class, you can now stylise your link with CSS :

```
ul.menu li.blue a {
    color: blue;
}
```

Screenshots :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGl8s.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVNoi.png

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ID, because ID will keep on changing when we delete the menu and created again. Instead of this use a separate class for that menu from Backed.
Check this link for more info: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/customizing-the-wordpress-menu-with-custom-classes/
or Use this 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60168/add-a-custom-class-to-admin-menus